# FragmentActivity always re-created and savedInstanceState always null

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragmentactivity

I have use Android Studio wizard to create a APP with Google Maps.
On main activity of my app there is a map where I can add some markers. Besides there is a menu to call other 3 activities.

When the user open a secondary activity then close it (for example pres back button or click on button to call finish) the secondary activity is close but the main activity is always re-create (onCreate method is call) and the map re-create so I lost markers and camera options.

I have try to use onSaveInstanceState to save markers and camera settings but I cannot restore it because savedInstanceState parameter of onCreate is always null.
I also have try to use onRestoreInstanceState but this method is never call, besides I have test onSaveInstanceState and this is call always when I try to open a secondary activity.

How can I avoid map is re-created every time?
Where is the problem with savedInstanceState?

This is an extract of my application code (main activity):

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener {
...

List<MapPoint> MapPointsList = new ArrayList<MapPoint>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    if (savedInstanceState !=  null) {
        mCurrentMapCenterLatitude = savedInstanceState.getDouble("mCurrentMapCenterLatitude");
        mCurrentMapCenterLongitude = savedInstanceState.getDouble("mCurrentMapCenterLongitude");
        mCurrentMapZoom = savedInstanceState.getFloat("mCurrentMapZoom");

        MapPointsList.clear();
        MapPolylinesList.clear();

        ArrayList<MapPointsParcelable> list;
        list = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("MapPointsList");

        for (MapPointsParcelable aList : list) {
            MapPoint mapPoint = new MapPoint(aList.name, aList.latitude, aList.longitude, aList.status, aList.kind);
            mapPoint.selected = aList.selected;
            MapPointsList.add(mapPoint);
        }

        mapRestore = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMap();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putDouble("mCurrentMapCenterLatitude", mCurrentMapCenterLatitude);
    savedInstanceState.putDouble("mCurrentMapCenterLongitude", mCurrentMapCenterLongitude);
    savedInstanceState.putFloat("mCurrentMapZoom", mCurrentMapZoom);

    ArrayList<MapPointsParcelable> list;
    list = new ArrayList<MapPointsParcelable>();

    for (MapPoint aMapPointsList : MapPointsList) {
        list.add(new MapPointsParcelable(aMapPointsList.name, aMapPointsList.latitude, aMapPointsList.longitude, aMapPointsList.status, aMapPointsList.kind, aMapPointsList.realname, aMapPointsList.selected));
    }

    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("MapPointsList", list);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(getApplication()).inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearchActivity();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettingsActivity();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_credits:
            openCreditsActivity();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            setUpMap();
        }
    }

    if (mLocation == null) {
        mLocation = ((LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE));
    }
}

private void openSearchActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

private void openSettingsActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}

private void openCreditsActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreditsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

...

}
```

Comment: What happens when you change "onCreate" with "onCreateView"?

Comment: I get an error about "Method 'onCreateView(android.od.Bundle) is never used'"